# How can I have a class check all of the other classes for collision detection?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am trying to practice programming through an object orientated approach.  I have created a class called orb that displays a graphic of a ball that bounces around the screen.  I want to add collision handling.  I think it would be best to fit the OOP approach by having the orb.update method handle the collisions.  However, to do this, I would need to access a list of the other orb objects.  Is there a way I can get a list of all the variables that have been declared with type orb?  If I could find this, I could then refer to the x and y variables of each of the orbs to make sure they are not too close to other orbs on the canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<script src="http://www.scottbunin.com/processing.js"></script>
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">
size(600,600);

orb h1 = new orb(100, 200, 5, 100); 
orb h2 = new orb(400, 200, 5, 100); 
orb h3 = new orb(400, 200, 5, 100); 

void setup(){
  size(600, 600);
  frameRate(120);
}

void draw() { 
  background(200);
  h1.update(); 
  h2.update();  
  h3.update();  
} 

class orb { 
  float xpos, ypos, speed, diameter, xOffset, yOffset, radius; 
  orb (float x, float y, float s, float size) {  
    xpos = x;
    ypos = y; 
    diameter = size;
    xOffset = s;
    yOffset = s; 
    radius = .5 * diameter;
    } 

  void update() { 
    ypos += yOffset; 
    xpos += xOffset; 
    if(yOffset<0&&ypos<0+radius){
        yOffset=-yOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(yOffset>0&&ypos>height-radius){
        yOffset=-yOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(xOffset<0&&xpos<0+radius){
        xOffset=-xOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(xOffset>0&&xpos>width-radius){
        xOffset=-xOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    noStroke();
    for(a = diameter; a > 0; a-=5){
        fill(0,0,255-a);
        ellipse(xpos, ypos, a, a); 
        }
  } 
  void imperfectEdge(){
    xOffset=xOffset+random(-.1,.1);
    yOffset=yOffset+random(-.1,.1);
  }

}


</script><canvas></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "common" way I'd say is to create a scene list: a list of all objects currently on the scene (in your case, the screen).

Let that scene handle all objects and you can refer to it's list to easily access all of them.
It's also useful for optimizing collision calculations, should you decide to study it further... (with quadtrees)

Comment: Thanks.  With this approach I handle the collisions not with the individual objects but as a group of objects on the canvas.